# How to change product URL and redirect?

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, base-url

Here's the situation I need to redirect one of my product to homepage make it as homepage at the same time the URL must be changed to home, so instead of **www.example.com/sample-product** it should be **www.example.com** take note that I am accessing this link **www.example.com/sample-product**.

I am also confused if I'm going to use the rewritten URL.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/136638/366250

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the rewrite where request path is `sample-product` and the target path is `../`. Anyone visiting the URL **www.domain.com/sample-product** will end up at **www.domain.com**. The default homepage will also need to be set to your product.

> 1. Navigate to **Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites**

Find the Magento path of the Product URL by looking within the Rewrite table. I typed in URL of product you want to be your homepage in target path and found request path for that particular product.

e.g. `catalog/product/view/id/1`

Make a note of this URL.

> 2. Navigate to **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages**

Set the **Default Web URL** to  your product e.g. `catalog/product/view/id/1`

Accessing **www.domain.com** will now show your product.

> 3. Navigate to **Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites -> Add URL Rewrite**

a. Set **Request Path:** `sample-product`

b. Set **Target Path:** `../`

c. Set **Redirect Type**: Permanent

This sets your product URL so that it will be redirected to the homepage also.

Comment: The product redirect but still, it display the homepage it should be displaying the product as the homepage. Thanks for your time to answer my question

Comment: Oh ok so you want the homepage to be that product page? And you can access this homepage via www.domain.com/sample-product and if you access www.domain.com?

Comment: Yes that's what we want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated answer

Comment: Glad you got it going, Could you mark as answer?

Comment: I need more 15 reputation unfortunately :(